# Injecting dependencies into controllers - angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the $modal service to invoke a controller and its respective template. it looks something like this :

```
$modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'someTemplate.tpl.html'
  controller: 'MyController',
  resolve: {
    variable1: function() {return data1;},
    variable2: function() {return data2;}
  }    
});
```

The point is when MyController is invoked variable1 and variable2 are resolved and passed into this controller

I now need to call this controller from elsewhere in the code (not via $modal service). How to I inject variable1 and variable2 in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**$controller**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24controller):

```
app.run(['$controller', function($controller){

   $controller('MyController', { 
      variable1: 'something' , 
      variable2: 'another'
   });

}]);
```